# Packing density of MOSFET

Tags: semiconductors

I read about it recently, that the packing density of MOS is more when compared to BJT and hence they are more preferred when it comes to memory design.

Why is it so?

Comment: I'd say MOS is preferred to BJT for memory design mainly because MOS only draws current when state changes.  Every thing else is secondary.

Comment: "Preferred" might not be the right word. I don't think it is even possible to build the typical types of memory using BJT's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MOSFETs are easier to scale down simply using W/L ratio. So on a given area, more MOSFET memory cells can be accomodated, compared to BJT. Also MOSFETs have low static power consumption, when holding a logic state in a memory cell. One more point is that, from the fabrication point of view, MOSFETs fabrication process is less complex, compared to BJT. So MOSFETs are a better choice for memories.

Answer (score 0):

The standard bipolar transistor has a tiny emitter, a base surrounding the emitter, and the collector + contact-sinker down to buried-layer under the collector, with all needing sufficient distance to not interact with other nearby implants.

This nest: emitter/base/collector/buriedlayer demands lots of area.